# Add metadata schema to Geonetwork from Github

Tags: metadata, geonetwork, schema

I have a local installation of GeoNetwork 3.10.4 where I want to add a metadata schema that is available on Github. The schema can be found here: https://github.com/geoadmin/geocat/tree/geocat_3.4.x/schemas - I want to add the schema `iso19139.che`.

I tried to copy the folder with its contents to the directory `web\geonetwork\WEB-INF\data\config\schema_plugins` but the new schema does not show up in the metadata and template section after I restart the application.

Also, I read that it should be possible to upload a ZIP-file with a new schema, but I don't see any place where I can upload a schema in the GeoNetwork admin section.

How could this particular (or any schema) be integrated to another GeoNetwork installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to import the schema by duplicating the jar file from Gemini (`schema-iso19139.gemini23-3.7.jar`), then change the extension to .zip and then edit all the files where gemini23 appears. I then renamed the jar file to the same name that my schema folder has and changed the extension back to .jar. Finally, I copied this new file to `INSTALL_DIR/geonetwork/WEB_INF/lib`

Also I had to add a line to the file `schema-ident.xml`:

```
<appMinorVersionSupported>3.4.0</appMinorVersionSupported>
```

After these changes, Geonetwork recognizes the new schema and I am able to import the templates.

Answer (score 2):

> Any hint on how this particular (or any schema)

Well the instructions provided for the GEMINI 2.3 schema found at metadata 101 https://github.com/metadata101/iso19139.gemini23 worked for me on 3.10.4.0

## Gemini 2.3 Metadata Profile schema plugin

Gemini 2.3 Metadata Profile

### GeoNetwork versions to use with this plugin

**Use the correct branch for your version of GeoNetwork. The default branch is for GeoNetwork 3.10 and this is the recommended version.**

### Installing the plugin in GeoNetwork 3.10.x (recommended version)

#### Adding to an existing installation

- Download or clone this repository, ensuring you choose the correct branch.
- Copy `src/main/plugin/iso19139.gemini23` to `INSTALL_DIR/geonetwork/WEB_INF/data/config/schema_plugins/iso19139.gemini23` in your installation.
- Copy `target/schema-iso19139.gemini23-3.7.jar` to `INSTALL_DIR/geonetwork/WEB_INF/lib`
- Restart GeoNetwork
- Check that the schema is registered by visiting Admin Console -> Metadata and Templates -> Standards in GeoNetwork. If you do not see iso19139.gemini23 then it is not correctly deployed. Check your GeoNetwork log files for errors.

Comment: Thanks, this works well for gemini23, but the schema I need (`iso19139.che`) does not have a jar file. Do you know how I could create the necessary jar file for my schema?
What is the best to edit an existing schema and add custom attributes, e.g. in gemini23?

Comment: Not sure if you need the JAR, I know that the GEMINI2.3 schema here also has additional validation through a schematron, and the jar may be helping to enforce those rules.  Sorry can't be of any more help.